# Euclidean Time Feynman Path Integral as Stochastic Differential Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, stochastic-processes, wick-rotation

For a quantum system with Lagrangian $L(x, \frac{dx}{dt})$ we can represent the action of a path $\mathbf{x}$ as $$S(\mathbf{x}) = \int_0^{t} L(\mathbf{x}(s), \mathbf{\frac{dx}{dt}}(s)) ds.$$ Then, the Euclidean evolution of a wavefunction $\psi(x, t)$ is given by the path integral
$$
\psi(x,t) = \frac{1}{Z}\int_{\mathbf{x}(0) = x} e^{-S(\mathbf{x})/\hbar} \psi(\mathbf{x}(t), 0) \mathcal{D}(\mathbf{x}).
$$
Since in the Euclidean case the complex numbers in the path integral are eliminated this seems reminiscent of an expectation over a stochastic differential equation. It seem like there should be some stochastic differential equation
$$
dx = \mu(x,t) dt + \sigma(x, t) dB
$$
such that
$$
\psi(x, t) = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}} [\psi(\mathbf{x}(t), 0)]
$$
where the expectation is over paths $\mathbf{x}$ sampled according to the stochastic differential equation. The Feynman-Kac formula seems like it might help provide this equivalence but I am not sure exactly how. Ideally I would like to know if this equivalence exists, is there a way to determine $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from the Lagrangian/Action or is there at least some equation relating the Lagrangian and the two functions determining the SDE.